# Name for continuous, increasing functions in (x,y) that cover (0,0) to (1,1).

Tags: functions, terminology

I am interested in the category of functions $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy:

- $f(0) = 0$
- $f(1) = 1$
- $f(x) \in [0,1]\ \forall\ x \in [0,1] $
- $f(x)$ is defined, continuous and strictly increasing $\forall\ x \in [0,1]$. For $x \notin [0,1]$, it doesn't matter what happens.

For example:

- $f(x) = x^k$ where $k > 0$
- $f(x) = 3x^2 - 2x^3$
- $f(x) = \sin(\frac{1}{2}\pi x)$
- $f(x) = \frac{\ln(x+1)}{\ln(2)}$
- Etc.

[image]

My question is: Is there a name for these kinds of functions? I want to find more, but I'm not sure what to search for.

Comment: @mweiss It says "I only care about real numbers, and I have no idea what any of these symbols mean, so here, let me guess random MathJax."

Comment: @mweiss No I don't, it only needs to be defined for $0 \leq x \leq 1$, I don't care about anything outside that range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of describing these functions is that they are "order-preserving continuous bijections of the unit interval with itself."  I'm not sure if there is a more concise way of saying that.

Answer (score 1):

Such functions are sometimes called automorphisms of the unit interval that leave the endpoints fixed, or increasing homeomorphisms of the unit interval. Googling various parts of these phrases (but not as a phrase search) will give you an idea of where such functions arise.